# make Qlayout not resize with parent

Tags: c++, animation, qt5, c++17, qlayout

consider following code -

```
class CollapsibleGroupBox : public QWidget
{
public:
    CollapsibleGroupBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr): QWidget(parent)
   {
    auto chk = new QCheckBox(this);
    chk->move(0, 0);
    chk->resize(width(), 12);
    setContentsMargins(0, chk->height(), 0, 0);
    QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "size");
    a->setDuration(1000); 

    connect(chk, &QCheckBox::toggled, [this, chk, a](bool c) {
        static int s = height();
        if (auto l = layout()) {
            if (c) {
                s = height();
                a->setEndValue(QSize(width(), chk->height()));
                a->start();
                //setMaximumHeight(chk->height() * 2);
            } else {
                qDebug() << s;
                a->setEndValue(QSize(width(), s));
                a->start();
                // setMaximumHeight(s);
            }
        }
    });
}

    bool isChecked() const;
    void setChecked(bool checked);

private:
    bool m_checked;
};
```

now when animation start, the layout also shrinks or grows with the widget, I don't want that I need to only show the part of layout that can be fitted into the current widget size, also shrinking layout's widget doesn't look good, I tried changing size policy but can't seem to find anything, Can anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

done with disabling layout ([QLayout::setEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#isEnabled)) on animation start and then enabling it back on animation end

PS: if anyone has a better solution please post.